# Docker / MySQL - Doctrine Migration - Access Database outside container

Tags: mysql, docker, doctrine

Hello :) here is my docker compose :

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  web-server:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    links:
      - "db:db"
  db:
    image: mysql:5.6
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - "8001:80"
    links:
      - "db:db"
    environment:
      MYSQL_USERNAME: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
```

As you can see, when i go to phpmyadmin with http://localhost:8001/ i have :

[PhpMyAdmin Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rw9gj.png)

Doctrine Migation is installed in my project, so when i try :

> ./vendor/bin/doctrine-migrations status

Errors are :

> In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 112:
> An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
> In Exception.php line 18:
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
> In PDOConnection.php line 39:
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
> In PDOConnection.php line 39:
> PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Connexion in my env file is :

```
BDD = pdo-mysql://root:root@db:3306/playlist_maker_multi
```

I expose port 3306 on my docker-compose so i don't understand why outside my container i can't access to my Database ?

Thanks everybody, if you have explanations.
Have a nice day.
Camille

Comment: Just to be clear, are you running your project with Doctrine Migrations on a project inside a container on the network (e.g. as part of "web-server") or on a project outside of the network (i.e. running normally on your local machine)?

Comment: When i run Doctrine Migration inside my docker container, i have no problems. I thought i can use doctrine outside of the network ? I thought my "db" hostname will be expose with 3306:3306 :/ it seems not :D

Answer (score 0):

Could you try running it with this config

I renamed the db service to `mysql`, explicitly added a network and made your php service depend on mysql, so it will restart untill it establishes a connection, just in case the php container starts running before the mysql container

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  web-server:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    links:
      - "mysql:db"
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.6
    container_name: db
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    networks:
      - net
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - "8001:80"
    links:
      - "mysql:db"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      MYSQL_USERNAME: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    networks:
      - net
networks:
  net:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, it seems it changes nothing when i run my doctrine command. But you config is very interesting, if think i'll use it.

Answer (score 0):

For applications running on your host machine but outside of your Docker network (i.e. not containerised) that need to connect to a container, you can use `localhost` instead of `db`, as the DNS name `db` is only valid inside the Docker Compose network.

With:

```yaml
mysql:
  image: mysql:5.6
  container_name: db
  ports:
  - "3306:3306"
```

you are creating a path from `locahost:3306` (or `MACHINEIP:3306` if on another machine) to the service on `mysql:3306` inside the network.

Answer (score 0):

@clarj, do you mean like that ?

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  web-server:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    links:
      - "localhost:db"
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: db
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - "8001:80"
    links:
      - "localhost:db"
    environment:
      MYSQL_USERNAME: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).